# How would you write a method that takes an optional inner function

Tags: scala

I'm not sure what this pattern is called, but could this be written in scala and if so how would I go about doing this?

```
val userId = 1

def getUser(userId: Int): User = {
 CacheLookup.getOrElse(userId) {
   userDao.get(userId)
 }
}
```

I guess this would be an anonymous function as a parameter?

Answer (score 2):

There's something similar to that on maps -- check mutable map's `withDefault`. The difference is that it doesn't *update* the map, which seems to be what you want (and, in fact, what many people using `withDefault` wants, by the questions we get here).

An alternative is *memoization*. You'd have to find that outside the standard library, but it works a bit like that except you don't do the cache thing explicitly. Basically, you write a function `userId => userDao.get(userId)`, and then you get a memoized version of it. When you call the memoized version, it will check whether there's a cached version for the parameter and serve that if so.

Note that there are important issues with the cache. Do you want/can have it increase indefinitely, or should it be limited? Will the keys expire after a time? This sort of control is important, and whatever solution you pick must support it.

As for how to implement it, it could go like this:

```
def memoize[A, B](f: A => B): A => B = {
  var map = Map.empty[A, B]
  (key: A) => {
    if (!map.contains(key)) map += key -> f(key)
    map(key)
  }
}

val getUser = memoize((userId: Int) => userDao.get(userId))
```

This memoization function takes a `Function1` (that is, a function with one parameter) and takes a `Function1` that does caching (in a very basic sense, without any of the controls I mentioned). For functions taking more parameters you'd have to create different versions of this, or make them *tupled*.

Then we get to the use, where I pass the function that takes an `userId` (an `Int`) and returns a `User`, and we get the same function back, but now doing caching.

Here's an example of tupling, just out of curiosity:

```
scala> val mult = memoize(((x: Int, y: Int) => x * y).tupled)
mult: ((Int, Int)) => Int = <function1>

scala> mult(2, 3)
res18: Int = 6

scala> mult(2 -> 3)
res19: Int = 6
```

The first call, `mult(2, 3)` is actually a Scala oddity. When calling functions that take a tuple, if you are passing multiple parameters then Scala will auto-tuple then.

Comment: can you explain the method parameter and return type a little please?

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking. If you're wondering how to implement the `getOrElse` method so that the database call would only be conditionally evaluated, the answer is to just use an ordinary higher-order function:

```
def getOrElse(userId: Int)(getter: Int => User) =
  if (cache contains userId) 
    cache get userId
  else
    getter(userId)
```